# Simple PHP SOAP request to ClickandBuy?

Tags: php, soap, payment

ClickandBuy provides lots of samples, but they are poorly coded and old. So I think there should be an easy PHP 5 SOAP solution for a simple SOAP payRequest with the PHP5 build in SoapClient class.

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://api.clickandbuy.com/webservices/pay_1_1_0.wsdl', array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
$client->payRequest(array('authentication'=>array(...), 'details'=>array(...)));
```

Works, but it returns an error:

*SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'description' property*

The arguments of the payRequest method should be fine. Did anyone try to implement ClickandBuy without NuSOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding description property into details array:

```
 $client->payRequest(array('authentication'=>array(...), 
    'details' => array(
      'description' => 'paying for shoes'
    )
));
```

Sample request:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <payRequest_Request xmlns="http://api.clickandbuy.com/webservices/pay_1_1_0/">
    <authentication>
       <merchantID>4000</merchantID>
       <projectID>1</projectID>
       <token>20100623104511::9E9C3E21FE38851B8913469F13619BD645BA1DD6</token> 
    </authentication>
    <details>
      <amount>
        <amount>1</amount> 
        <currency>EUR</currency>  
      </amount>
      <orderDetails>
         <text>My Cart</text>
      </orderDetails> 
      <successURL>http://www.mydomain.com/success.php</successURL>
      <failureURL>http://www.mydomain.com/failure.php</failureURL>
      <externalID>Test123</externalID>  
    </details> 
 </payRequest_Request>
```

Comment: Take a look at sample what data you need to send, particular orderDetails.

Comment: Looks like "description" referred to a missing description in the orderDetails itemList. Thx.